# Handling relationship with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have two models to make a relationship between them, where I need to access stores of a radar and the radars of a store. A radar could monitoring zero or many stores. A store could belong to zero, one or many radars.

I would like to have something like this:

```
store = Store.first
store.radars #all radars of the store location
```

And the opposite too:

```
radar = Radar.first
radar.stores #all stores of the radar location
```

My classes:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :user, :store_group, :city, 
                  :neighborhood, :sublocality, :post_code, :route,
                  :street_number, :latitude, :longitude
end

class Radar < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :radius, :latitude, :longitude, :user
end
```

How can I create a migration to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between radars and stores.    The question you need to ask your self is will there ever be any attributes on the the joining between the two models? If so you might considering using an explicit join model, that will hold those attributes. In that case you would be looking at a `has_many :through`  association.

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association  for information on the HABTM association.

your migration for a HABTM would be something like this.

```
class CreateRadarStores < ActiveRecord::Migration

 create_table :radars_stores, :id => false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :radar
      t.belongs_to :store
    end
end
```

The order of the table name is important, since by default rails creates it in alphabetical order of the models.

Your models would need to be updated to include the HABTM

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :radars
  ....
end

class Radar < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :stores
 ....
end
```

or if using a has many :through  look here  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Building that join model would be up to you depending upon attributes reuqired.

Comment: Hi Doon! Thanks for replying! Using `has_and_belongs_to_many`, on every radar's creation will have a store associated to radar on `radars_stores` table and it's a problem, because not every radar creation will necessarily have a store associated to it. How can I define, using this way, a condition to set if a radar will have a store associated? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  No where in the code above does it create any records, all that does it tell AR to build the association helpers, so your radar objects would have #stores and your stores would have #radars (and the other helpers).   So if `Radar r`, belong to `Store s`, you would need to do something like `r.stores << s` or `s.radars << r` to create the link between the 2. To tell if Store X has no radars, you could do something like `x.radars.empty?`.  Are you asking how you conditionally associate a radar with a store or vice versa on creation?

Comment: Doon, I used `has_and_belongs_to_many` and migration as you mentioned above. So, what's happening now when I'm adding a radar:

`Started POST "/radars"
  Parameters: {"radar"=>{"name"=>"[FILTERED]", "radius"=>"825", "latitude"=>"-23.5505199", "longitude"=>"-46.63330939999997"}}
  Store Load (0.3ms) SELECT 'stores'.* FROM 'stores'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO 'radars' ...
   (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO 'stores_radars' ('radar_id', 'store_id') VALUES (9, 1)
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT`

Every time I add a radar it automatically add a row on `stores_radars`,I need to handle this step. How?

Comment: please show your `RadarController` specifically the `create` method. but where did the `stores_radars` table come from, it should be `radars_stores`

Comment: Doon, it's working now! The problem was on create method, I added a validation to set stores on radars as you said. Thank you very much!